# Is the following a vector space? : The set of all solutions of the differential equation $y''+y=\cos t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

I understand I can show something is a vector space by showing it is a subspace using the three known axioms. I know I can find the general solution of the DE and seeing if it is a vector space. But can I re-write the equation into a system of first order equations, like so?

$x_1'=  x_2$

$x_2'= -x_1 + \cos t$

But then how do I show it now? Does it even contain the $\vec 0$ vector?

Comment: The function $y(t)=0$ does not satisfy the ODE so it is not a solution. This implies that the set of solutions (your candidate to vector subspace) is not a vector space. By the way the linear combination of any two nonzero solution would not be in the vector-subspace-candidate also so...

Comment: @mathbeing so if it was y''+y=0, then this would be a vector space?

Comment: Yes; $y(t)=0$ obviously satisfies the ODE, and $\lambda y_1(t)+y_2(t)$ also satisfies it if $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ satisfy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set $V $ is only a vector space if it complies with some axioms, one of which is the existance of the null vector, $0$. Now just note that $y=0$ does not solve your equation, meaning that the set of all its solutions is not a vector space.

Comment: is is still not a vector space if y''+y=sint? what if t=0

Comment: @Struggling_College_Student isn't $t $ the variable of which $y $ depends? Or is it a constant. If it is the variable, then you need $0$ to be a solution for any value of the variable $t $. So even knowing that for $t=0$ the equality would hold, it does not hold for $t=1$ for example.

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be solutions. Then $L[y_1 + y_2] = \cos t + \cos t = 2\cos t \neq \cos t$ so it is not closed under addition.

Answer (score 0):

However, it is an *affine space*, i.e. it is a vector space translated by a particular solution, since the set of differences of any two solutions *is* a vector space.